# Get Checkbox Value From DataGridTemplateColumn of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="grdData" ... >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Something">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox Name="chb" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

i try this code to get Checked State

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < grdData.Items.Count ; i++ )
{
    DataGridRow row = ( DataGridRow )grdData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( i );
    var cellContent = grdData.Columns[ 1 ].GetCellContent( row ) as CheckBox;
    if( cellContent != null && cellContent.IsChecked == true )
    {
       //some code
    }
}
```

my code is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are looping over the `Items` collection which is your `ItemsSource`. Why not to have the `bool property` in your class itself and get it from there itself.

Say if ItemSource is `List<Person>`, then create a bool property say `IsManager` in class `Person` and bind it with your checkBox like this -

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsManager}"/>
```

Now you can loop over the Items to get the value like this -

```
foreach(Person p in grdData.ItemsSource)
{
   bool isChecked = p.IsManager; // Tells whether checkBox is checked or not
}
```

**EDIT**

In case you can't create a property, i would suggest to use the `VisualTreeHelper` methods to find the control. Use this method to find the child (Maybe you can place this in some utility class and use it, since its generic) -

```
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
           where T : DependencyObject
{
   // Confirm parent is valid.  
   if (parent == null) return null;

   T foundChild = null;

   int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
   for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
   {
      var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      // If the child is not of the request child type child 
      T childType = child as T;
      if (childType == null)
      {
          // recursively drill down the tree 
          foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

          // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child.  
          if (foundChild != null) break;
      }
      else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
      {
          var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
          // If the child's name is set for search 
          if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
          {
             // if the child's name is of the request name 
             foundChild = (T)child;
             break;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          // child element found. 
          foundChild = (T)child;
          break;
       }
   }
   return foundChild;
}
```

Now use the above method to get the state of your checkbox -

```
for (int i = 0; i < grd.Items.Count; i++)
{
   DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grd.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
   CheckBox checkBox = FindChild<CheckBox>(row, "chb");
   if( checkBox != null && checkBox.IsChecked == true )
   {
       //some code
   }
}
```

Comment: my class is generated from EF. and that Boolean is not needed in my class

Comment: Updated the answer with another approach. See if this helps.

Comment: this method is not working when i am using on tab control where i have different datagrid on different tab item.its not working on my second tab where i am uisng another datagrid.