# How to get <checkbox> state inside <datagridtemplatecolumn> on any row's checkbox event in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a datagrid - dgUserSession in my WPF application. 
It contains 3 columns where only 2 text columns are bound with database and first one is checkbox created manually.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Name="userSelection" Checked="DataGridCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="DataGridCheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Checked="chkHeader_Checked" Unchecked="chkHeader_Unchecked" Name="headerSelection">
                                            </CheckBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to iterate through each rows state in all four events

```
private void chkHeader_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < dgUserSession.Items.Count; i++)
        {
}
}
```

But how to get the checkbox is wether checked or not during this iteration?
I spent 3hrs in goggle but no result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to do something like : var mycheckbox = dgUserSession.Columns[0].GetCellContent(.....) as Checkbox for every row's checkbox and perform operations based on Checked or Unchecked result.

Comment: You have not posted anything about the properties you are binding

Comment: This is manually created checkbox - to perform some task. If a checkbox in row is checked then perform the task. I m not binding any property. This is as it as xaml of my page.

Comment: @sapatelbaps I am not sure am completely understood your problem, why dontyou use a "DataGridCheckboxColumn" and bind its state?

Comment: @sapatelbaps what you mean by i need double click ?

Comment: @user1767798 I need to doubleclick on checkbox to mark it check unlike in normal window by single click we can do check/uncheck any checkbox.

Comment: @sapatelbaps as far as i know i dont remeber, you need to select that row then one click to check and one to uncheck thats all

Comment: Finally got solution as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880335/get-checkbox-value-from-datagridtemplatecolumn-of-datagrid?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, it is *always* best to create your data type classes *in the form that is required by the UI*. By that, I mean that instead of data binding to two of the three columns in your `DataGrid`, you should be binding to all three columns. If you add a `bool` property into the class that is being displayed in each row of the `DataGrid`, then you can get access to the value of the `Checkbox` from that class.

If you have not data bound a collection of a custom type to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, then I'd recommend that you do that. Just create a class (that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) and has a property for each column (3 in your case). Then data bind an `ObservableCollection` of that type to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Items { get; set; }
```

...

Then in the property setters of your `YourDataType` class, you will have access to the values of each property/column each time any value is changed:

```
public someType SomeProperty
{
    get { return someProperty; }
    set 
    {
        someProperty = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
        // each time this is changed, you have access to the other property values here
    }
}
```

You can also iterate through the collection to find the values of the `Checkbox`es:

```
foreach (YourDataType item in Items)
{
    bool checkBoxValue = item.NewBoolProperty;
}
```